# ValueError: empty range for randrange() (6,6, 0)

Tags: python

I wrote this code it worked at first but then it showed error. cant figure out the problem. Ps: i'm new to programming.

```
import random
for i in range(0,100):
    a = random.randint(0,5)
    b = random.randint(a+1, 5)
    print(b)
```

> I got Output -- 2 ValueError                                Traceback
>   (most recent call last)  in 
>         2 for i in range(0,100):
>         3     a = random.randint(0,5)
>   ----> 4     b = random.randint(a+1, 5)
>         5     print(b)
>
> C:\tools\Anaconda3\lib\random.py in randint(self, a, b)
>       220         """
>       221 
>   --> 222         return self.randrange(a, b+1)
>       223 
>       224     def _randbelow(self, n, int=int, maxsize=1<
>
> C:\tools\Anaconda3\lib\random.py in randrange(self, start, stop, step,
>   _int)
>       198             return istart + self._randbelow(width)
>       199         if step == 1:
>   --> 200             raise ValueError("empty range for randrange() (%d,%d, %d)" % (istart, istop, width))
>       201 
>       202         # Non-unit step argument supplied. ValueError: empty range for randrange() (6,6, 0)

Answer (score 2):

A short modification of your code explains why it throws an error

```
import random
for i in range(0,100):
    a = random.randint(0,5)
    print(a)
    b = random.randint(a+1, 5)
    print(b)
```

Basically, a + 1 can be > 5, which is bad...

Comment: Thanks , i guess i'll try with just a,or use an if statement with a<5.

Comment: or you can change it to  a = random.randint(0,4)

Answer (score 2):

When the intial randint statement a = random.randint(0,5) initializes to 5, the second statememt becomes b = random.randint(5+1, 5) where the start integer for randint is greater than the end integer. This causes an error as shown.